# What does the build() method do with the Response in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I found a code like this:

```java
response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(object.toString()).build();
```

Can anyone please explain me what exactly that `entity(...).build()` will do with the response?

Comment: Please post more of your code. At least provide the import statements or if you know, the used libraries.

Comment: It will create a response containing the result of `object.toString()`. Or do you need a more detailed explaination? In that case please specify what you need in your question.

Comment: Yes, I need to know more information about this. what that `entity` and `build()` means

Comment: It is calling the build method which implies a Builder pattern is used here. It will construct the response object based on `object.toString()` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) cannot be instantiated directly. It uses the *[Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)*, which is one of the 23 well-known [GoF design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) that describe how to solve recurring design problems in object-oriented software.

The Builder design pattern aims to solve problems like:

- How can a class (the same construction process) create different representations of a complex object?
- How can a class that includes creating a complex object be simplified?

Instead of [instantiating objects directly with `new`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), the object creation is **delegated to a builder**, which allows you to have control over the steps of the construction process.

---

Inspect the [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) [constructor summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in the class documentation. You will find a [single `protected` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#Response--), which cannot be invoked directly from your code.

Instead, you must use one of the [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) [static methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#method.summary) to obtain a [`ResponseBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) instance and then obtain a [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) from that.

[`ResponseBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) allows you to control how the [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) is built, defining a status code, an entity, response headers, cookies, etc. Once you are done, you invoke [`build()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#build--) and it will return a [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instance.

Let's have a look at each step:

```java
Response.status(Status.OK)         // Create a new ResponseBuilder with the supplied status
        .entity(object.toString()) // Set the response entity in the builder
        .build();                  // Create a Response instance from the ResponseBuilder
```

---

Another well-known example of the Builder design pattern usage is the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

`public static Response.ResponseBuilder status(int status)` method returns a [ResponseBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) . With this builder you can provide Response attributes and then call build method to create a Response object. 
You can read more about the builder pattern on book Effective Java 3rd Edition Item 2.